# How can I move the decimal point to the 100ths of an integer?

Tags: javascript, parsefloat

This seems like a silly question but I cant figure out how to convert an integer number that represent cents to dollars.

3000 -> 30.00

in javascript...

I was using ParseFloat but it's only giving me back the integer =/ I need to always display the cents even if its 0.

Answer (score 52, accepted):

[Use `toFixed()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/toFixed).

```
var num = 3000;

alert( (num/100).toFixed( 2 ) ); // alerts 30.00
```

Answer (score 1):

You can divide by one hundred, and then call the `toFixed` method to format it to two decimal places.

`myNumber.toFixed(2)`

Edit: "Then" was "ten" :\

Answer (score 1):

Try something similar to:

```
document.write(x.toFixed(2));
```

Answer (score 1):

I combined the `toFixed(2)` method others have provided with a pre-existing [currency formatter](https://www.npmjs.com/package/currency-formatter) if anyone stumbling upon this finds it handy.

[cents-to-currency](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cents-to-currency)

Not trying to do any self-promo or anything :D